# Word Identification - Act/Believe of living in harmony with nature

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a virtue or character trait relating to the belief or practice of living in harmony with nature.  It should not have any negative or derogatory connotations, nor should it imply any sort of primitiveness as the people in question might well be very technologically advanced.

Natural or naturalness are the best that I have come up with, but they also both seem a little bland and on the nose.

Something like savage or barbaric is closer to what I'm aiming for, but obviously those both have a negative tone which precludes them from being used a virtue for which someone might be praised.  Uncivilized is also similar, but would imply the backwardness that I'm trying to avoid also.

Example: The people of Utopia have learned the value of ________, so that, while they have not sacrificed their technological advancement, they have been careful to keep their progress sustainable and to remain conscious of their environment at all times.

Answer (score 1):

This may have too many connotations and be distracting, but Tao is an excellent word for this

> ### Tao:
>
> 1.) the unconditional and unknowable source and guiding principle of all reality as conceived by Taoists
> **2.) the process of nature by which all things change and which is to be followed for a life of harmony**
>
> From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Tao)

Answer (score 0):

One word that fits well is [Environmentalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmentalism)

The people of Utopia have learned the value of **environmentalism**, so that, while they have not sacrificed their technological advancement, they have been careful to keep their progress sustainable and to remain conscious of their environment at all times.

Personally I might consider

The people of Utopia have learned the value of **essence**, so that, while they have not sacrificed their technological advancement, they have been careful to keep their progress sustainable and to remain conscious of their environment at all times.

Spiritual essence is used in many ways to describe the soul, however on its own essence may be used to describe an affinity with nature.

Answer (score 0):

> The people of Utopia have learned the value of being **at one** with
>   nature, so that, while they have not sacrificed their technological
>   advancement, they have been careful to keep their progress sustainable
>   and to remain conscious of their environment at all times.

**at one**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/12597?rskey=Ny3EFm&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> In a position of unity of feeling; in harmony, concord, or friendship

Another example:

> R. Buchanan God & Man I. 171   The maiden, in her sweet..content, was
>   **at one** with Nature.

Answer (score 0):

Commensalism

Definition of commensalism

: a relation between two kinds of organisms in which one obtains food or other benefits from the other without damaging or benefiting it

Mutualism

mutually beneficial association between different kinds of organisms